# integrity constraint (...) violated - child record found, Java, Oracle, Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I need no update Values when update Crypto, but delete all child Values when delete Crypto:

```
class Crypto {
...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="cryptoId", updatable=false)
    private Set<Values> values;
...
}


class Values {
...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cryptoId")
    private Crypto crypto;
...
}
```

SQL debug when I delete Crypto:

> Hibernate: delete from "Crypto" where "id"=?

Error:

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (ARTIKUA.FK_8R5C0WLWJ3LIJTVJ559EV8NAT) violated - child record found

DB is Oracle
Why Hibernate, before delete "Crypto", don't delete all their child "Values" values?

Comment: How are you deleting the Crypto object instance? via HQL?

Comment: session = sf.openSession(); session.delete(); session.close();

Comment: Can you paste your complete code? It is strange that session.delete(crypto) is not deleting the child instances. Do you load the crypto object before delete?

Comment: Crypto cry = session.get(Crypto.class, 5); session.delete(cry);

Answer (score 1):

If you are deleting the Crypto object through hql, hibernate cannot not cascade the delete operation. Since the cascade is a hibernate configuration matter (i.e. hbm.xml or annotations) the data must be returned to Java for processing of cascades. Doing UPDATE/DELETE row modifications in HQL happens entirely on the database server.

What you can do:

1. fetch all Crypto instances that should be removed. for each of them.
2. Call entityManager.remove() or session.delete().

Comment: I use session.delete(), but why I need fetch all elements? There only need that Hibernate make something like "DELETE FROM `Values` WHERE `cryptoId`=" + Crypto.getId(), before delete Crypto

Comment: That would be a HQL query. I didn't completely follow. Are you using session.delete() or hql query? Post your complete code in your question

Comment: Crypto cry = session.get(Crypto.class, 5); session.delete(cry);